# iOS - Received memory warning for showing an image on Today Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage

I am trying to download an image from a RSS feed and then show it in today extension widget , the problem is even showing a simple image causes Memory Warning  !:

```
_imageView.image = [UIImage imageName:xxx.jpg];
```

here is my code to download image using `UIImageView+AFNetworking`:

```
[_wImage setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[item.imagesFromContent objectAtIndex:0]]]
```

even tried with `NSData` :

```
  [_wImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                                  [NSURL URLWithString:[item.imagesFromContent objectAtIndex:0]]]]];
```

the result still is `Received memory warning.`

Comment: memory warning doesn't mean that you have written wrong code. It means you are taking more space than expected. You should change your implementation to avoid memory warning. Also there is a difference between memory leak and memory warning

Comment: @InderKumarRathore yes but widget crashes !!!!

Comment: What is your downloaded data size ?

Comment: @vivekDas between 100 to 200 kb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved ! for those who will face with this problem , you must resize your image simply by :

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage :(UIImage *)theImage :(CGSize)theNewSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(theNewSize, NO, 1.0);
    [theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theNewSize.width, theNewSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

My image was 1024 x 768  and its size was 100 to 200 kb ! so with this code you shrink its size and save a lot memory .

Answer (score 3):

Extensions have much lower memory limits than a normal iOS app. I suggest rethinking your architecture and doing less work in the extension itself.

Comment: I think you are completely right. Can we find out what is the limit of memory for the extension?